# Add value to list item depending on another list item value

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, object-construction

I am using this code to populate a list in C# with data from a Web Api that gets data from a csv file

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:12345/api/items");

var info = new List<SampleDataGroup>();

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);

    foreach (var data in item)
    {
        var infoSect = new SampleDataGroup
        (
            (string)data.Id.ToString(),
            (string)data.Name,
            (string)"",
            (string)data.PhotoUrl,
            (string)data.Description
        );
        info.Add(infoSect);
    }
}
else
{
    MessageDialog dlg = new MessageDialog("Error");
    await dlg.ShowAsync();
}
```

I would like to assign a photo to `(string)data.PhotoUrl,` depending on its `Name`.

For example: If the `Name` is "Car", I would like it to be assigned the `PhotoUrl` "Assets/Images/car.jpg". If an item in the lists `Name` is "Boat", assign it's `PhotoUrl` to "Assets/Images/boat.jpg".

The Images are not included of the CSV file that the web api feeds on.

There will be more than one item in the list with the same `Name`, but all with the same `Name` will share the same assigned image.

How do I do this?

Comment: what's stopping you using `if else condition`? `if(data.Name == "Car") { display car pic ...Assets/Images/car.jpg } else if .....`

Comment: Would that be the best way? Then there would be about 15 statements.

Comment: you can use if else or switch statements

Comment: can you not use string.Format?  `url = new Uri(string.Format("...Assets/Images/{0}.jpg",data.Name));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `info` in `new info`? Is it some class of yours? If yes, does it inherit from the `SampleDataGroup` type you typed your list with? If yes and you are assigning values to it using a constructor, then use

```
data.PhotoUrl = string.Format("Assets/Images/{0}.jpg", data.Name)
```

Doing this with `if/else` as mentioned in comments would be a suicide. IF not now, then surely when you decide to expand.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake above. `info` should be `SampleDataGroup`. See the edit above. `SampleDataGroup` is a structure defined in my data model of my application.

Comment: @Tester All right. Does my answer solve your problem or do you need something else?